# Identify this beetle from Bangladesh

Tags: zoology, species-identification, entomology

Location: Bandarban, Bangladesh

[image: view 1]
[image: view 2]
[image: view 3]

Comment: It is from Coleoptera (beetle), right?

Comment: Where did you find this insect? Inside your home? If so, where? What "habitat" was this insect in?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This appears to be some species of beetle (order [Coleoptera](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beetle)) in the [Bostrichidae](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bostrichidae) family.

- Commonly called **auger beetles, false powderpost beetles, or horned powderpost beetles**.

[image] [image]

<sup>[Xylopsocus capucinus](http://entnemdept.ufl.edu/creatures/trees/false_powder_post_beetle.htm)</sup>

Identification to species can be difficult, but fortunately for you [Sittichaya et al (2009)](https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Wisut_Sittichaya/publication/38105834_An_illustrated_key_to_powder_post_beetles_Coleoptera_Bostrichidae_associated_with_rubberwood_in_Thailand_with_new_records_and_a_checklist_of_species_found_in_Southern_Thailand/links/00b7d522681acce741000000/An-illustrated-key-to-powder-post-beetles-Coleoptera-Bostrichidae-associated-with-rubberwood-in-Thailand-with-new-records-and-a-checklist-of-species-found-in-Southern-Thailand.pdf) created an **illustrated key** for IDing species associated with South Asia.

Based on their key and visual characteristics of your specimen, my guess is that your specimen is ***Xylopsocus capucinus***

[image]

<sup>**Source: [Sittichaya et al 2009](https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Wisut_Sittichaya/publication/38105834_An_illustrated_key_to_powder_post_beetles_Coleoptera_Bostrichidae_associated_with_rubberwood_in_Thailand_with_new_records_and_a_checklist_of_species_found_in_Southern_Thailand/links/00b7d522681acce741000000/An-illustrated-key-to-powder-post-beetles-Coleoptera-Bostrichidae-associated-with-rubberwood-in-Thailand-with-new-records-and-a-checklist-of-species-found-in-Southern-Thailand.pdf)** . **a.** lateral view; **b.** elytral declivity; **c.** intercoxal process of the 1st abdominal ventrite; **d.** dorsal view.</sup>

- Description: 3-5.5 mm long; 1.4-1.7 mm wide. Shape is cylindrical and similar in general appearance to other common species of the family Bostrichidae.
- Distribution: throughout South and Southeast Asia from India to the Indonesian archipelago.
- Hosts: apparently polyphagous attacking almost any woody plant in suitable condition.
- Phenology: adults emerge mainly
  between May and November.

Like most false powderpost beetles, the head cannot be seen from above as it is downwardly directed and hidden by the thorax:

[image]

<sup>Source: [UFL IAFS](http://entnemdept.ufl.edu/creatures/trees/false_powder_post_beetle.htm)</sup>

---

**Sources:**

- Sittichaya, W., Beaver, R., & Ngampongsai, A. (2009). [An illustrated key to powder post beetles (Coleoptera, Bostrichidae) associated with rubberwood in Thailand, with new records and a checklist of species found in Southern Thailand](https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Wisut_Sittichaya/publication/38105834_An_illustrated_key_to_powder_post_beetles_Coleoptera_Bostrichidae_associated_with_rubberwood_in_Thailand_with_new_records_and_a_checklist_of_species_found_in_Southern_Thailand/links/00b7d522681acce741000000/An-illustrated-key-to-powder-post-beetles-Coleoptera-Bostrichidae-associated-with-rubberwood-in-Thailand-with-new-records-and-a-checklist-of-species-found-in-Southern-Thailand.pdf). ZooKeys, 26, 33.
- Woodruff RE, Gerberg EJ, Spilman TJ (2005). [A False Powder-post Beetle, Xylopsocus capucinus (Fabricius)
  (Insecta: Coleoptera: Bostrichidae)](http://entnemdept.ufl.edu/creatures/trees/false_powder_post_beetle.htm). University of Florida, IFAS Extension Publication No. EENY-179.
  Institute of Food and Agricultural Sciences, University of Florida, 4 pp

Answer (score 1):

This appears to be a **Powder-Post Beetle** (order **Coleoptera**, family **Bostrichidae**); a local reference is needed for further identification.

Comment: Please provide a reference for your identification if possible.

Comment: The post by @theforestecologist gives you a good example of how a well-researched answer to a species ID question looks like, even though your ID is also correct - as far as I can tell, and that is the problem: it needs some effort for me to check even though answers should be self-explanatory. Please try to give more comprehensive answers.